# Doubt in K-L Transform equations

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals

I have a doubt, it may be silly. Please explain me.

In K-L Transform, For forward transform we have the below equation

[image]

For inverse transform we have the below equation

[image]

In reverse transform why the 'A' transpose is not common to both y and m(mean of x) as in Forward transform equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=A(x-m_x)$-->$A^Ty=A^TA(x-m_x)=x-m_x$-->$x=A^Ty+m_x$